# What is the syntax to nest queries on ruby?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linq, activerecord

i have to translate a query written in sql into ruby (activeRecord / Linq), but i can't find the correct syntax to do it, please help.

i want to know the number of unique users who did this 4 activities in a festival. the sql query is the following:

```
`SELECT count(distinct user) FROM stats where festivalId='fest000'
and user in (select user from stats where activity='checkins')
and user in (select user from stats where activity='programs')
and user in (select user from stats where activity='status')
and user in  (select user from stats where activity='pictureUpload');`
```

how can i manage to do it? 
where can i find at least similar examples or good documentation to figure it out? 
would it be possible to use a constant "user" so i can do all the queries and then put them together or something like this?

i am desperate,i cant find a solution and i dont know what to do... thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to find out distinct user count which having `festivalId='fest000'` and `activity 'checkins' AND  'programs' AND 'status' AND'pictureUpload')`

Then following query should work

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats 
WHERE festivalId='fest000' AND activity IN ('checkins', 'programs', 'status','pictureUpload') 
GROUP BY user 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT activity) = 4
```

And you can easily convert this query in ruby way too

```
Stat.where("festivalId=? AND activity IN (?)", 'fest000', ['checkins', 'programs', 'status','pictureUpload']).group('user').having("COUNT(distinct activity) = 4").count
```

Comment: THATS IT salil!! thanks for your help!